# How to reverse sql selection

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, reverse

So this is my code but i need to reverse it after the selection, this way it would just display newest messages on the top ... But i need them on the bottom. So is there a way i can reverse it? Help me please ... I was trying to find the solution but i couldnt find it anywhere.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE sender = '$savedUid' AND getter = '$currentChat'
OR sender = '$currentChat' AND getter = '$savedUid' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20";
```

Comment: Just remove the `DESC` and it will sort ascending by default. Can also add `ASC` if you want to be explicit

Comment: If you need to take the latest 20 messages and order them from the older to the newer, use a Subquery.

SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM messages WHERE sender = '$savedUid' AND getter = '$currentChat'
    OR sender = '$currentChat' AND getter = '$savedUid' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20) sub
 ORDER BY sub.id ASC

Comment: Thanks man! This worked fine!

Comment: It not work if you simply remove DESC from your query?

Comment: Like: $sql = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE sender = '$savedUid' AND getter = '$currentChat'
OR sender = '$currentChat' AND getter = '$savedUid' ORDER BY id LIMIT 20";

Comment: Order by always take ASC order by default and DESC only needs to give if you want to select data in DESC order.